# how to get records of a table whose id's are taken from a select statement

Tags: mysql, having, nested-statement

I have two tables. I try to select some records from one of them. Then, ID's part of that selection should be used to select some records of the other table. For that, I wrote a statement which takes long time for execution. I even couldn't see the results.
Also, that broke my phpmyadmin from localhost.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM uniquestructures as uns WHERE uns.ProteinID IN (SELECT unp.* FROM uniqueproteins as unp HAVING LENGTH(unp.PDBASequence) < 20) as T)
```

To make it clear, first it selects records with all columns which have sequence length less than 20. Later, according to IDs of the selected records, I am searching the records have the same ID (as ProteinID)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: firstly - you might want to read up on JOIN syntax. Secondly, how many rows are in uniquestructures and in uniqueproteins? Also - try replacing unp.* with (guess) unp.ProteinID

Comment: ah. Just twigged. Is the uns.ProteinId comparable to a concatenation of all of the columns in the uniqueproteins table?

Comment: I used also LEFT JOIN. Uniquestructures and uniqueproteins have the same size and same ID information--20370 rows. But the rows have sequence length less than 20 are 2228. So, I need to select each id in that 2228 and return the row in uniquestructures which has that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you need to use an `INNER JOIN` with a `DISTINCT` here:

```
SELECT distinct uns.*
FROM uniquestructures as uns 
INNER JOIN uniqueproteins as unp on uns.ProteinID = unp.ProteinId
where LENGTH(unp.PDBASequence) < 20;
```

Also, you might have some joy if you create a separate column on the `uniqueproteins` table to hold the length of the `PDBASequence` column (say `PDBASequenceLength`). You could then put an index on the `PDBASequenceLength` column rather than calling `LENGTH(PDBASequence)` in your query. If the data is not static then create a trigger to populate the `PDBASequenceLength` column each time a row is inserted or updated into the `uniqueproteins` table. Hence:

```
CREATE TRIGGER uniqueproteins_length_insert_trg
AFTER INSERT ON uniqueproteins FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.PDBASequenceLength = length(new.PDBASequence);

CREATE TRIGGER uniqueproteins_length_update_trg
AFTER UPDATE ON uniqueproteins FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.PDBASequenceLength = length(new.PDBASequence);

alter table uniqueproteins add key `uniqueproteinsIdx2` (PDBASequenceLength);
```

Your query could then be:

```
SELECT uns.*
FROM uniquestructures as uns 
INNER JOIN uniqueproteins as unp on uns.ProteinID = unp.ProteinId
where unp.PDBASequenceLength < 20;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I checked my code and added distinct and worked for even left join. But I wonder, why does the code I posted not work? Just to learn :) Could you explain it?

Comment: No problems! The problem is in your sub-select i.e. ...(select unp.*... this needs to be changed to ...(select unp.ProteinId.... I suggested using an inner join since this is usually a better approach than nesting sub-selects.

Comment: PS If it worked then you may want to indicate this by accepting the answer :)